# Regex which grabs everything between two characters at the end of a line

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm looking to create a regex which grabs the text between two ":"s but only if it is the "last set", for example:

```
\--- org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1
```

should return:

```
http-builder
```

It should be noted that it's possible to get something like:

```
\--- org::codehaus::groovy::modules::http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1
```

because the input does not necessarily follow conventions (based on the problem at hand) but the required information is ALWAYS in the last two ":"s.

I've tried some of the following (minus the end of line):

```
1) (?<=\:).*(?=\:)
2) [^(.*:)].*[^(:.*)]
3) :.*: (this was the most successful, although I got the ":"s with the result but there are issues when there is more than one set of ":"s)
```

Futher information:

- I need to use Groovy for this
- I can read it using a stream or a file (in case that matters)

Thanks for reading and any help!

Comment: How would you treat a GAV which has a [classifier](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html). Like `groupId:artifactId:packaging:classifier:version`

Comment: For my issue, I never have that; but you'd have to figure out some pattern that would let you know if that's what it is or not.
Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
:([^:]*):[^:]*$
```

That means:

- Sequence must start with a `:`
- Then start capturing `(`
- Capture all characters that are not colons `[^:]*`
- End capturing `)` ...
- ... at the next colon `:`
- Then there's another sequence of chars `[^:]*`
- And after that sequence the line **must** end `$` (no more sequence)

Or if you can use non-greedy matches, you can also use

```
:(.*?):[^:]*$
```

`.*` means capture as many characters as possible, while `.*?` means capture as little characters as possible. Not all regex implementation support that, though.

Answer (score 3):

How about splitting on the `:` and grabbing the next-to-last segment?

```
['org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1', 
 /\--- org::codehaus::groovy::modules::http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1/].each { line ->

    assert 'http-builder' == line.split(':')[-2]
}
```

Comment: Nice groovy solution.